# VBS expected statement error

Tags: vbscript, compiler-errors

I keep getting a Error Expected statement. Code 800A0400. Line 1, char 1. What am I doing wrong?

My code,

```
# $language = "VBScript"
 # $interface = "1.0"

' Connect to an SSH server using the SSH2 protocol. Specify the
' username and password and hostname on the command line as well as
' some SSH2 protocol specific options.

 Sub Main

  Dim host
  host = "ssh.google.com"
  Dim user
  user = "userinfo"

  ' Prompt for a password instead of embedding it in a script...
  '
  Dim passwd
  passwd = crt.Dialog.Prompt("Enter password for " & host, "Login", "", True)

  ' Build a command-line string to pass to the Connect method.
  '
  cmd = "/SSH2 /L " & user & " /PASSWORD " & passwd & " /C 3DES /M MD5 " & host

  crt.Session.Connect cmd

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "comment to end of line" marker in VBScript is the single quote `'`, not `#`. So change

```
# $language = "VBScript"
 # $interface = "1.0"
```

to

```
' $language = "VBScript"
' $interface = "1.0"
```

(Other possible problems: do you **call** Sub main? Where does crt come from?)

Comment: Thank you that got rid of it. I am not calling sub main at the moment.  I just copied this script form a tutorial form to try and learn how this works so that I can implement it into my main script.